# If statement using a user input

Tags: matlab, if-statement, user-input

I'm trying to write a code that asks the user to type "heart" and if this is typed a graph of a heart will appear. But I keep getting an error saying "undefined function or variable 'heart'" This is what I have. The graph works fine if it's run by itself so that's not the problem. Thanks!

```
result = input('Type "heart": ','s');
if (result == heart)
    t = linspace(-pi,pi, 350);
    X = t .* sin( pi * sin(t)./t);
    Y = -abs(t) .* cos( pi * sin(t)./t);
    plot(X,Y);
    fill(X, Y, 'r');
    set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'));
    title('Happy Anniversary!', 'FontSize', 28);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use strcmpi assuming you want case insensitive compare

```
result = input('Type "heart": ','s');
if (strcmpi(result,'heart'))
    t = linspace(-pi,pi, 350);
    X = t .* sin( pi * sin(t)./t);
    Y = -abs(t) .* cos( pi * sin(t)./t);
    plot(X,Y);
    fill(X, Y, 'r');
    set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'));
    title('Happy Anniversary!', 'FontSize', 28);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put heart inside quotes:

```
result = input('Type "heart": ','s');
if (result == "heart")
    t = linspace(-pi,pi, 350);
    X = t .* sin( pi * sin(t)./t);
    Y = -abs(t) .* cos( pi * sin(t)./t);
    plot(X,Y);
    fill(X, Y, 'r');
    set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'));
    title('Happy Anniversary!', 'FontSize', 28);
end
```